# How to pass values from JSTree Menu to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the example in -

http://codemyne.net/articles/Populating-Treeview-with-checkboxes-using-MVC3Razor-Jstree-Jquery.aspx?visitid=149&type=2

I want to pass values of the selected node to the controller. The author of the article is displaying the values in a message box; **I want to show the selected item's text or id** it in a **TextBox**  in the same page or pass it **to the controller**. Can anyone help me to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: I followed this - http://codemyne.net/articles/Populating-Treeview-with-checkboxes-using-MVC3Razor-Jstree-Jquery.aspx?visitid=149&type=2 link; the author is passing the values to a message box, I want to pass it to a textbox in the same page or pass directly to the controller. I am using Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
function getChecked(){
    divId = [];

    $("#onflycheckboxes").jstree("get_checked", null, true).each(function () {
       divId.push(this.id);              
    });

    $.ajax({
       url: "/MyController/Action",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {divIds: divId},
       contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8"
    })
}
```

MVC Controller (`MyControllerController.cs`)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(object[] divIds=null)
{
   //break here and view the results of divIds.
   return Json("success");
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael,I will try this; not sure about breaking the result within Action (public ActionResult Action(object divIds=null))

Comment: I was saying to put a break point in on the `return` line so you can watch the `divIds` you are getting.

Comment: When I add '(object divIds=null)' to the Action in Controller page the call does not go to the function. If I leave it blank like - ActionResult Action() it goes to the function, but I don't get the values. I had to add extra "" marks to get the function working like -   
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/Action",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data": "{divIds: divId}",
                    "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8"
                } How do I pass to Action or at least to a Text Box

Comment: You pass to action by calling `getChecked()` if you have the function setup like my answer.  the `.ajax` does a POST to the url sending the data `divIds` to the controller.  You should see a value..if you aren't check to see if `divId[]` has values by doing `console.log(divId);`

Comment: Hi Michael, In the Action Method in the controller, if I DON'T give (object divIds=null)
it will work; if I leave Action method blank (Action()), I will not be able to pass value. I am using the same code you have posted. Any clue!

Comment: Hi,I changed  type to GET instead of "POST" within the ajax function (type: "GET",) and now the call goes to method; but all I can see is "divIds = {object}". I can't get the value

Comment: Try `object[] divIds=null` <-Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also, add `[HttpPost]` attribute to use 'POST'

Comment: I tried the new code as well; but no luck. If i leave Action method's receiving end blank, then it will work; Just like - Action(). I think if I use a text box in the same page, then when the user selects an item the item should be sent to the text box and then call the function. not sure how to pass to the text box.

Comment: I found an article related to this query. This may help people who come to this post - http://codemyne.net/articles/Populating-Treeview-with-checkboxes-using-MVC3Razor-Jstree-Jquery.aspx?visitid=149&type=2